# How to refactor code with try-catch-finally

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have to create a bunch of methods that look like this.  The things that change will be the method name, the return type and the lines marked in the middle - the rest will be the same.  Is there a **clean** way to refactor this so that I don't repeat myself?

```
private bool CanPerform(WindowsIdentity identity, string applicationName, int operation)
{
    IAzApplication3 application = null;
    IAzClientContext3 context = null;
    try
    {
        application = this.store.OpenApplication(applicationName, null) as IAzApplication3;

        ulong token = (ulong)identity.Token.ToInt64();
        context = application.InitializeClientContextFromToken(token, null) as IAzClientContext3;

        // lines that change go here
    }
    catch (COMException e)
    {
        throw new SecurityException(string.Format("Unable to check operation '{0}'", operation), e);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(context);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(application);
    }
}
```

I realise this is probably basic stuff but I work alone so there's no one else to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like a delegate would be appropriate here, with a generic method to cover the return type changing:

```
private T ExecuteWithIdentity<T>(WindowsIdentity identity,
    string applicationName, int operation,
    Func<IAzApplication3, IAzClientContext3, T> action)
{
    IAzApplication3 application = null;
    IAzClientContext3 context = null;
    try
    {
        application = this.store.OpenApplication(applicationName, null) as IAzApplication3;

        ulong token = (ulong)identity.Token.ToInt64();
        context = application.InitializeClientContextFromToken(token, null) as IAzClientContext3;

        return action(application, context);
    }
    catch (COMException e)
    {
        throw new SecurityException(
            string.Format("Unable to check operation '{0}'", operation), e);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(context);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(application);
    }
}
```

Then you put the code for each check in a separate method, or even just use a lambda expression:

```
bool check = ExecuteWithIdentity(identity, "Foo", 10,
                         (application, context) => context != null);
```

or

```
string check = ExecuteWithIdentity(identity, "Foo", 10, SomeComplexAction);

...
private static string SomeComplexAction(IAzApplication3 application,
                                        IAzClientContext3 context)
{
    // Do complex checks here, returning whether the user is allowed to
    // perform the operation
}
```

You may want to change the delegate type of course - it's not clear what `operation` is meant to be used for, for example.

I would also strongly consider casting instead of using `as`. If the application or context is returned from `OpenApplication`/`InitializeClientContextFromToken`as a non-null value which just isn't the right type, do you really want to handle that the same was as a null value being returned?

Comment: But what if the return type has to change?  I did think of delegates (though not of Func<blah> - I've still to get used to them) but I couldn't see a way to make that work.

Comment: @SGarratt - The you would have to make the method generic as well. The method signature would then look like this: `private bool CanPerform<T>(WindowsIdentity identity,
                        string applicationName, int operation,
                        Func<IAzApplication3, IAzClientContext3, T> predicate)`

Comment: @SGarratt: One option is to create a new class, e.g. `PermissionContext` and put all the relevant information in there. Then the predicate would be `Func<PermissionContext, bool>` - if you need to add more information, you can add it to the `PermissionContext`.

Comment: I meant the return type of the original method.  This one is private bool CanPerform.  What if I need private string GetTaskFromOperation(...)?

Comment: @SGarratt: Ah - I hadn't spotted that the return type would change. In that case, make it a generic method. Will edit for that.

Comment: I missed a comma out of my opening sentence - sorry.

Comment: Thank you, Jon.  The frustrating thing is that I know about generics.  And I've even used them.  But they're clearly not integrated in with everything else.  Will your book teach me that?  Not just teach me how generics work but help integrate them into my mental model of C# so that I think of such solutions?

Comment: @SGarratt: It's not clear what you mean by "not integrated in with everything else". I certainly cover quite a lot about generics, but I'm not sure whether it'll help fill whatever hole you have...

Comment: They're not integrated with everything else in my (ageing) brain.  :-(  Guess I should buy it and find out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do your error handling slightly higher up the stack, so rather than catching and rethrowing the exception inside the method you could do it where the method is called?

If your method calls are all wrapped in a Manager class that might save a bit of time. If they're just ad-hoc called everywhere then naturally maybe not :)

I hope that might help.